# Failing to update App Settings on Azure Function When MSI is Enabled

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I have a function with Managed Service identity enabled. When I try to update app settings via Azure portal I am getting following error.

**Failed to update web app settings: ["{\"error\":{\"code\":\"CannotRemoveResourceIdentity\",\"message\":\"Resource identity of type 'SystemAssigned' already exists on resource and can not be removed.\"}}"]**

I have tried disabling MSI and then changing the App settings, but it failed to update with same error.

Is this a known issue with MSI and Azure Functions?

Comment: I got the same problem trying to update an SSL cert :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and a fix is being worked on / deployed. I’ll update this post as I learn more on the status.

-- update --

This GitHub issue is tracking this and has a workaround in meantime [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/1977)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively as a work-around you can go to https://resources.azure.com.

You can also find it in functions from Platform features -> Resource Explorer.

Find your function, and go to config -> appsettings. You should be able to update them from here.

I solved my problem with updating the SSL certificate on a Web App in this way.

Comment: I had the same error when trying to set an SSL binding and using the resources worked. If you wonder what's the right JSON to PUT, just use the browser tools to spy the request the portal makes and then replay it but include the identity as well.